# Looking for a part: I want to put a vertical hinge onto a standing pipe

Tags: pipe, structural, hinges, play-structures

I would like to attach some kind of pivoting hinge onto a 1/2" - 3/4" metal pipe (e.g. galvanized or cast-iron):

[image]

Something almost like [this](https://mobileimages.lowes.com/product/converted/032888/032888188952.jpg) but instead of bolting onto a flat surface, it clamps onto a pipe.

Suggestions or helpful things to google are all welcome

Comment: use a short section of a chain

Comment: I'm not sure how this would work.  I don't want the smaller pipe to move other than the rotating motion in the same plane as the large pipe.  If I understand correctly, a small chain would allow for movement in a number of different axes

Comment: your question does not specify that the motion has to be constrained to a specific plane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm interpreting the question as: I'd like to clamp on some hardware to a pipe which would allow me to attach and rotate another pipe on the same plane as the original pipe.

If you already have the part in your post and you want to figure out a way to make it fit, you can use that part along with two u-bolts, just position the u-bolts at the width of the bolt holes. [image: Muffler clamp]

Your other option would be to buy some purpose built hardware from the local industrial supply. Here's a page that has some hardware that I think will spark your interest: https://www.zoro.com/modular-pipe-and-rail-fittings/c/5624/ [image: Swivel socket]

Good luck on your project!

Comment: `I'd like to clamp on some hardware to a pipe which would allow me to attach and rotate another pipe on the same plane as the original pipe.` Yes, exactly